# Calling python multiprocessing script in different script

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a script multiprocess.py containing something like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

abc = np.load('somedata.npy')

def func(k):

    fret1 = k+abc*k
    fret2 = k+5*k^2
    fret3 = k-abc
    
    return fret1, fret2, fret3

def worker(k):
    try:
        result = func(k)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred for k={k}: {e}")
        return None

def run_mp():
    xyz = np.random.random(100)
    iterator= range(len(xyz))

    # Create a list to store the results
    results = []
    ret1    = []
    ret2    = []
    ret3    = []

    # Use multiprocessing.Pool to run worker function in parallel
    with Pool(os.cpu_count()-1) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, iterator) 
    
    # Filter out None values (occurred due to errors)
    results = [result for result in results if result is not None]
    # Unpack the results and collect ret1, ret2, and ret3 values
    for fret1, fret2, fret3 in results:
        ret1.append(fret1)
        ret2.append(fret2)
        ret3.append(fret3)

    print("Multiprocesssing complete")
    np.savez('data.npz', xyz=xyz, ret1=ret1, ret2=ret2, ret3=ret3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_mp()
```

Standalone it runs just fine but I want to call it in another python script like so:

```
with open("multiprocess.py") as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I get an infinite loop.

I also tried to open the script with this command:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("multiprocess.py") as f:
        exec(f.read())
```

And also this:

```
from multiprocess import run_mp

run_mp()
```

PS: I am working and trying to run the code in Spyder on Windows if that somehow matters.

Comment: You did not post what error you are actually getting. But you need `from multiprocess import run_mp; if __name__ == '__main__': run_mp()`

Comment: Oh that one is smart. I missed calling the function with `if __name__ == '__main__':` That solved my issue.

Comment: @David: I mention it in my answer, but just to make it clear: *ALWAYS* follow *all* [the `multiprocessing` programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) when on Windows. Ideally follow them everywhere (for portability), but if you can *rely* on `'fork'` as the start method (meaning you're running only on Linux/BSD/UNIX, never Windows, and only on macOS if you explicitly set the start method to `'fork'` and risk crashes), then the spawn/forkserver guidelines aren't critical. If you violate those guidelines, terrible things happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused, independently, in 2-3 different ways:

1. When not using `exec`, you fail to use the import guard on the invocation of `run_mp`
2. Using `exec` to define things will screw up `multiprocessing` in various ways
3. (Depends on IDE) IDEs are typically death to `multiprocessing` (they don't invoke the script the normal way, and `multiprocessing`'s required invariants aren't established correctly)

Problem cause #1 is the simplest: Invoking `run_mp` outside an import guarded section means that, in any start method mode but `'fork'` (which is not *available* on Windows) it tries to recursively invoke it in each worker, so the main process spawns a pool of workers to do work, which in turn try to spawn a pool of workers apiece to do the *same* work, but none of them ever managed to actually *do* any work.

On problem cause #2, specifically, when dispatching tasks to workers, `multiprocessing` uses the `pickle` module to serialize the functions and their arguments. Functions are pickled by their qualified name, and `pickle` confirms that that qualified name is legal by looking it up directly. This has three implications:

1. You can't pass `lambda`s to `Pool.map`, even if you've assigned them to a name, e.g. `foo = lambda x, y: x + y` (because the name they report is `modulename.<lambda>`, not `modulename.foo`)
2. `exec` will break things when not invoked at global scope (because the module in question is not imported, and because the `globals` it's checking for stuff like `__name__` will report the module it is being `exec`ed in, not the module it came from).
3. Even when `exec` is executed at global scope (which would mean `pickle` could find the defined names), if the `exec` occurs in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guarded block, it won't be executed in the child process, so the *unpickling* in the worker process will fail, even though the *pickling* in the parent process succeeded.

On problem cause #3, `multiprocessing` is frequently broken by running in an IDE at all, because many IDEs actually do something quite similar to `exec`-ing your script from an IDE wrapper that is the *actual* `__name__ == "__main__"` script; even if the test still claims that `__name__ == "__main__"` in your script, when `pickle` checks `sys.modules['__main__']` for your function, it ends up finding the skeleton module the IDE actually ran, not your "real" script, and things break (this can also happen when running a `multiprocessing` script under profiling, `python -mcProfile myscript.py` has `cProfile` as the `sys.modules['__main__']` entry, not `myscript`).

To fix these issues:

1. Don't run `multiprocessing` scripts in an IDE (nor from an interactive terminal), period. Run them from the command line in an independent terminal (e.g. on Windows, `cmd.exe` or Powershell, ideally running via the Windows launcher if installed as admin with the box for it checked, e.g. `py -3 path/to/script.py`)
2. Don't use `exec` (this is a good idea in general, it's a hacky way to do what `import`ing would do for you more correctly, more concisely, and often more efficiently, since the cached import only gets loaded once per process, not loaded for every `exec`; there are use cases for `exec`, but they're very narrow, it should never be the first, second, third, or even fourth tool you're reaching for)
3. Use your `import` guard consistently; when you used `import`, you didn't guard the invocation of `run_mp`, so the process of launching the workers would try to run `run_mp` in each worker. This is a critical part of [the `multiprocessing` programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) when running on a Windows system (where `'spawn'` is the default and *only* available start method), and it's a good idea to adhere to it elsewhere (e.g. macOS defaults to `'spawn'` in recent versions of Python, with `'fork'` being available, but dangerous due to non-`fork`-safe system libraries, and even on Linux/BSD, some people will choose to use `'spawn'` or `'forkserver'` start methods when the parent process could be huge and the default `'fork'` would potentially consume a lot of memory, possibly crashing the process(es) or triggering the OOM Killer due to excessive virtual memory usage).

In short, your final example usage was almost correct (if invoked from a separate script, not an interactive session, not via an IDE). You just need to change it to:

```
from multiprocess import run_mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_mp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying this on Py 3.11, with a dummy 'multiprocess.py', it looks like it fails to Pickle the functions when executing as a subprocess (exec part).

My recommendation is to instead use import and call "run_mp()" method, instead of executing the script.

My "multiprocess.py" code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

My "main.py" script:

```
def exec_work():
    exec(open("multiprocess.py").read())


def import_call():
    from question.multiprocess import work
    work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec_work()   # <-- fails due to pickling
    import_call() # <-- works fine
```

Everything is in the same directory, to avoid any import issues!